Group equivalent row attributes together in SQL
I have a table that stores the same phone numbers but with different attributes.
Without changing the schema, I want to group up all the phones and sort them by their createdat and organizationid parameters.
Here is an example:
Unordered results:



id
phone
createdat
audienceid
organizationid




1
7877777777
Apr 2024
1
2


2
7877777777
May 2024
2
2


3
7877777777
Aug 2024
5
1


4
7877632794
Jan 2024
5
1


5
7877777777
Mar 2024
3
1



Ordered results:



id
phone
createdat
audienceid
organizationid




2
7877777777
May 2024
2
2


1
7877777777
Apr 2024
1
2


3
7877777777
Aug 2024
5
1


5
7877777777
Mar 2024
3
1


4
7877632794
Jan 2024
5
1



The order of the phone numbers or the organizationid's are not important, what maters is that the phones are grouped together and sub grouped by organization, each sub-group is sorted based on the createdat date desc.
Right now I'd like to explore different methods of accomplishing this goal and if it's more efficient if the phone numbers are only grouped and not ordered, same for the organizations.

ORDER BY does magic when you have to order data

You're going to need to elaborate a bit more on what specifically you're talking about when you say "group", since the term has a very specific meaning in a SQL context. The example you've given does not in any way make any indication that any grouping (again, in the SQL definition of the term) is actually happening. It would also help if you could show us the query you have so far, what output that's giving you, and where specifically you're getting stuck in getting that query to the result you're expecting.

Do you want to just order the results or group the results too? For grouping, you'd need to use at least one aggregate function.

...ORDER BY phone, organizationid, createdat desc

esqew above put it well. Grouping in SQL means reducing multiple rows sharing some features down to a single one per group. Your grouping seems to mean listing them together without reduction, which order by does easily and efficiently. Any way you try to group, be it in the SQL sense or yours, you'll find that ordering is commonly a side effect because it's easy to establish peer groups by sorting.

For this sample data and expected result the correct order by is phone desc, organizationid desc, createdat desc:
WITH    --  S a m p l e    D a t a :
    tbl (id, phone, createdat, audienceid, organizationid) AS
( Select 1, 7877777777, DATE '2024-04-01', 1, 2 Union All
  Select 2, 7877777777, DATE '2024-05-01', 2, 2 Union All 
  Select 3, 7877777777, DATE '2024-08-01', 5, 1 Union All 
  Select 4, 7877632794, DATE '2024-01-01', 5, 1 Union All
  Select 5, 7877777777, DATE '2024-03-01', 3, 1  )

--    S Q L :
Select    *
From      tbl
Order By  phone desc, organizationid desc, createdat desc

/*      R e s u l t :
id  phone       createdat    audienceid   organizationid
--  ----------  -----------  -----------  --------------
2   7877777777  2024-05-01             2               2
1   7877777777  2024-04-01             1               2
3   7877777777  2024-08-01             5               1
5   7877777777  2024-03-01             3               1  
4   7877632794  2024-01-01             5               1    */

fiddle
NOTE: It is unclear how same phone number could belong to different  organizationid(s). I would expect that one organizationid has multiple phone numbers and that any particular phone number could belong to one and only one organizationid. If that is the case with real data - then to show the data in a way based on "what metters" would be organizationid, phone, createdat desc. This would keep together organizationid(s) with it's phone numbers (kept together too) and create date descending as asked for.

To clarify on what you mentioned on the phone numbers, these phone numbers represent an organization's clients, not the phone number of the organization itself.

I think what you're asking for is an ORDER BY statement:
ORDER BY phone ASC, createdat DESC, organizationid ASC

Simply add it to the end of the query. You can list as many columns as you need at it will order them by those columns in that order of preference. Use ASC and DESC for ascending and descending respectively.

order by is off, should be phone, organizationId, createdat desc. based on "what maters is that the phones are grouped together and sub grouped by organization, each sub-group is sorted based on the createdat date desc"  this answer would have create date putting the sub organizationId out of sequence.
